# Why does my hibernate join only return queries from one table?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hibernate-criteria

My query is:

```
            List<EmpModel> EmpData = sess2.createCriteria(EmpModel.class)
          .setFetchMode("TestModel", FetchMode.JOIN)  
          .add(Property.forName("id").in(emp_ids)).list();
```

Now, the query fired is completely correct. It returns a one-to-one join of the test and emp tables. However, The returned print statement only gives me the values from the EmpModel table. I believe the reason for this is that the emp_ids mentioned above always comes up as zero for which every value in the test table is null. Can someone tell me how to get over this error?

Comment: What is the definition of `EmpModel`? Does it contain a collection of the joined entities?  Your question is incomplete without a lot more context.

Comment: Yes It does... It contains a collection, all the mappings are right. I mean, is there a way to get the proper query out without having them right?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the criteria to return `TestModel` instances also, you can add another criteria and and a result transformer. You didn't post your entities, so if for example `EmpModel` has a property  `testModel`:

```
List<<HashMap<String, Object>> EmpData = sess2.createCriteria(EmpModel.class)
  .add(Property.forName("id").in(emp_ids))
  .createAlias("testModel", "tm")
  .setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP)
  .list();
```

Notice that the return type is changed from `List<EmpModel>` to `List<<HashMap<String, Object>>`, because now the query will return a list of `HashMap`s. Each HashMap will have a `"this"` entry pointing to a `EmpModel`, and a `"tm"` entry (the alias we assigned when building the query) pointing to the corresponding `TestModel`.

PS: I removed the `setFetchMode` from the code. Somehow that doesn't work with the above approach.

Comment: It turns out the problem was with the mapping. But thanks anyway!